# Handling Warnings in Hybris Console

Tags: spring, tomcat, warnings, sap-commerce-cloud

Going through my tomcat log, I have noticed this warning:

```
 WARN  | localhost-startStop-1 |   |  | ReleaseStrategyFactoryBean:116 | No target supplied; falling back to SequenceSizeReleaseStrategy
```

And I was wondering if there was a way to prevent this warning from appearing in the console?

EDIT: apparently, and according to this [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/1065), the warning happens if no method name is provided and no
annotated method is found, or a null reference is provided.

So if I'm not mistaken it's something internal to Spring, and therefore I can't do anything to stop the warning from appearing in the console?

Answer (score 1):

As an option you can disable logging for this particular **ReleaseStrategyFactoryBean**

It can be done via project.properties or local.properties.

Depending on the Hybris version you are running you should use either:

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.integration.config.ReleaseStrategyFactoryBean=off
```

or for  Hybris 6.XXX please reffer to this article:

https://help.hybris.com/6.1.0/hcd/42d818c7bac44eed9ab01757472b9dbc.html

And example is following:

```
log4j2.logger.hmc.name = de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.hmc
log4j2.logger.hmc.level = warn
log4j2.logger.hmc.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What's strange is, when I added the line log4j.logger.org.springframework.integration.config.ReleaseStrategyFactoryBean=off to coinfig/local.properties and even when I replaced it with log4j.logger.org.springframework.integration.config.ReleaseStrategyFactoryBean=ERROR, I could see the change on HAC but the log continues to show up in hybris console.

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue with your code.

From the Jira issue : https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3298

> The ReleaseStrategyFactoryBean should emit a WARN log if there is a ref attribute and no method attribute is found, and no annotated method is found. Currently, it silently falls back to using the SequenceSizeReleaseStrategy.
>
> In 4.0, we could make this fatal.